# change url to always have a prefix

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

i'm having a blazor WASM app, made with .net 7.0

my login urls are:

```
ggggg.com/{companyName}
```

after that all my urls are: (i want this to support copying links and sending it to another person, and then it will know what company this belongs to, so it redirects to the correct login page).

```
ggggg.com/{companyName}/products
ggggg.com/{companyName}/users
```

My question is, is there a way i can append this to the baseUrl of navigationManager, because i dont want to have to, grap the {companyName} from the url and adding it to all urls on that specific page.

so is there a way i can change the baseUrl after login or some other ideas that will make it possible for me not to create all Urls like `navigate.To($"{companyName}/page3");`

Answer (score 0):

You could build a wrapper service around the NavigationManager. Something like this:

```
 public class CompanyAwareNavigationService
 {
        private readonly NavigationManager navigationManager;
        private readonly string? companyName;

        public CompanyAwareNavigationService(NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            this.navigationManager = navigationManager;

            var relativeUri = navigationManager.Uri.Replace(navigationManager.BaseUri, "");

            var segments = relativeUri.Split('/');
            if (segments.Length > 1)
            {
                companyName = segments[1];
            }
        }

        public void NavigateTo(string uri)
        {
            var url = $"{companyName}/{uri}";
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
        }
 }
```

Please note that this code is not bulletproof. But you should get the idea.